# Eclipse's Content Assist does not work for java.util.Comparator

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm defining a field in a class like this:

```
Comparator<String> test = ...
```

In place of those three dots, if I write the first few letters of a static method of any of the classes listed in `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favorites`, and then press Ctrl + Space, I get auto-complete proposals for those methods (as expected), except for any static member of `java.util.Comparator`

My list of favorites is:

- `java.time.LocalDateTime`, getting lots of proposals after typing `of`
- `java.util.stream.Collectors`, same thing after typing `toli`
- `org.hamcrest.Matchers`, same thing with `not`
- `org.junit.Assert`, same thing with `assertt`

The only one not working is `java.util.Comparator`. I tried removing and adding it again, but didn't help. Adding the members to the favorites list instead of the type helps, but it's not the answer I'm looking for.

I'm using Eclipse 2019-03, with OpenJDK 12 on Debian Linux. Also tried with OpenJDK 8.

Here are some screenshots that might be useful.

[image: Favorites]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497423) related to generic types. `Comparator` is the only type in your list that is generic, but the same problem occurs with other generic types, for example `Optional`. Unfortunately there does not seem to be a fix yet.